# How can I 'row bind' two pandas dataframes with different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The number of columns are the same for two data frames but they have different column names.

How can I vertically bind two data frames?

Comment: Add sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: Please provide some sample dataset and expected output along with what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df2.columns=df1.columns
pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
```